# Image of an operator is a hyperplane

Tags: operator-theory

Let $a<b$. For the operator
$A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$,
$$
A(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1-a,x_2-x_1,x_3-x_2,\ldots,x_n-x_{n-1},b-x_n)
$$
that is $A(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(y_1,\ldots,y_n,y_{n+1})$,
$$
y_1=x_1-a,\quad y_i=x_i-x_{i-1}, \,\, i=\overline{2,n}, \quad y_{n+1}=b-x_n
$$
it is true that the image of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the hyperplane,
$$
A(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{(y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}: \, y_1+\ldots+y_{n+1}=b-a\}.
$$
I proved this but it seems very strange to me. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $A(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \{(y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}: \, y_1+\ldots+y_{n+1}=b-a\}$ is immediate.

For the reverse inclusion, let $(y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $y_1+\ldots+y_{n+1}=b-a$. Then define for each $k=1, ..., n$,
$$x_k = \left(\sum_{j=1}^k y_j\right) + a$$

You can easily check that $A(x_1, ..., x_n) = (y_1, ..., y_{n+1})$.